# Half of element disappearing in the bottom border of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to recreate google gravity for my secret Santa website, but for some reason after getting the google gravity JavaScript working on my page, half of a element that obeys to gravity disappear at the bottom boarder of webpage.
Even after I setted the overflow:hidden .
[image]

My html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="rescources/base.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="rescources/index.css">
        <title>My Github page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="/" class="logo">Freya Newman</a>
            <div class="header-right">
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/Shop">Shop</a>
                <a href="https://github.com/bensonchow123/secret-santa-website/">Source code</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="background-video">
        <source src="rescources/rickroll.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <h1 class="box2d text" id="center">Welcome to the secret santa website</h1>
    <h2 class="box2d text"> test </h2>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rescources/box-2d.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rescources/gravity.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My css for the body

```html
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
#background-video {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

#center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

My webpage is https://www.freya-newman.ga/ 
My code on GitHub is at https://github.com/bensonchow123/secret-santa-website 
Google gravity website https://mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google-gravity/

Answer (score 1):

For animated elements just set margin to zero, as:

```
#center {
    margin: 0;
}
```